# React router error " Objects are not valid as a React child..."

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Im starting with react router and exporting and importing routes.
I have `{casaRoutes}` imported from a file

```
const routes=[
  <Route path="/casas/create" element={Create} exact key="create" />,
  <Route path="/casas/edit/:id" element={Update} exact key="update" />,
  <Route path="/casas/show/:id" element={Show} exact key="show" />,
  <Route path="/casas/" element={List} exact strict key="list" />,
  <Route path="/casas/:page" element={List} exact strict key="page" />,
];

export default  routes;
```

But i still get this error `Objects are not valid as a React child...`

How can i render the imported routers ..

Im using "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `react-router-dom` v6 the `Route` component's API changed a bit from v5. The routed components are rendered on the `element` prop ***as `ReactElement`s***, a.k.a. *JSX*.

```
const routes = [
  <Route path="/casas/create" element={<Create />} key="create" />,
  <Route path="/casas/edit/:id" element={<Update />} key="update" />,
  <Route path="/casas/show/:id" element={<Show />} key="show" />,
  <Route path="/casas/" element={<List />} key="list" />,
  <Route path="/casas/:page" element={<List />} key="page" />,
];
```

Then be sure to import and render into the `Routes` component.

```
<Routes>
  {routes}
</Routes>
```

Answer (score -1):

What you could do is a React Component that exports your routes, or even doing so in your index.jsx

```
import { render } from "react-dom";
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Routes,
  Route
} from "react-router-dom";
// import your route components too

    render(
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/casas/create" element={Create} exact key="create" />,
          <Route path="/casas/edit/:id" element={Update} exact key="update" />,
          <Route path="/casas/show/:id" element={Show} exact key="show" />,
          <Route path="/casas/" element={List} exact strict key="list" />,
          <Route path="/casas/:page" element={List} exact strict key="page" />,
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>,
      document.getElementById("root")
    );
```

Find references in the docs:
https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview